# Camera not rendering to rendertexture inside class

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, cubemap, rendertexture

I have an issue where I created a class to generate a lightprobe atlas texture for me, but the camera don't seem to render properly into teh rendertexture, I have no idea why...

someone can help me found what I did wrong?

```
private void setCameraData(){

    //set camera
    pivot = new GameObject("CaptureScene");
    pivot.AddComponent<Camera>();

    //Set camera parameters
    lens = pivot.GetComponent<Camera>();
    lens.backgroundColor = Color.blue;
    lens.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
    lens.allowMSAA = false;
    lens.cullingMask = 1 << 8;//what mask?
    //should probably have an alternative for regular scene rendering
    lens.SetReplacementShader(capture, "RenderType");

    //set rendertexture
    sceneCapture = new RenderTexture(cubemapSize, cubemapSize, 24);
    sceneCapture.dimension = UnityEngine.Rendering.TextureDimension.Cube;
    sceneCapture.antiAliasing = 1;
    sceneCapture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    sceneCapture.graphicsFormat = UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.GraphicsFormat.R8G8B8A8_UNorm;
    sceneCapture.depth = 16;
    sceneCapture.Create();

}


public  void updateCell(int x, int y){
    //this fonction capture a cubemap of the scene from the point of view of a given cell
 
    //place camera
    int midcell = cellsize / 2;
    //-------------------- hashed position
    pivot.transform.position = new Vector3((x * cellsize) + midcell, 0, (y * cellsize) + midcell);
    pivot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

    lens.RenderToCubemap(sceneCapture);

    updateTile(x, y);
}
```

The rendertexture seems to be stuck into gray, I can't figuring out why. This is a refactor code, technically I got it to work initially in the old code, but there seems to be no notable difference with the new code except it's now in a class and cleaned up of dead code...